# What functional groups can 900-2500nm IR spectrometers detect?

Tags: ir-spectroscopy

3700 cm-1 corresponds to about 2,700 nm

650 cm-1 corresponds to about 15,000 nm.

Many cheap IR spectrometers ($7000 or so like the ones at Stellarnet) has range of 900nm to 2400nm (or 11,111 cm-1 to 4166 cm-1). In the following table or list of the molecules functional groups, the range is between 2700nm to 15,000 nm (3700 cm-1 and 650 cm-1). Outside of the range of cheap IR spectrometers. So what functional group or stuff can you see with IR spectrometers that has range below 2400nm (above 4000 cm-1)?

https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/biology/ir-spectrum-table.html

[image]

see the link above for complete list

Answer (score 2):

You recall vibrations IR spectrometers detect in the range of $4000\dots\pu{800 cm^{-1}}$ typically are either *fundamental vibrations* and *combinations*.  Tuning for shorter wavelengths / higher wavenumbers however renders recording absorptions about *overtones* instead of fundamentals more likely.  On occasion, you may encounter this part of the electromagnetic spectrum accessed by the larger UV-Vis-NIR spectrometers (e.g., PerkinElmer [Lambda](https://www.perkinelmer.com/product/lambda-1050-2d-system-l6020056) series) with a spectral range from $175\dots\pu{3300 nm}$); here, NIR is the label about *near infrared*.

The typical overtone is less probable than the fundamental, thus -- in parlance of Beer-Lambert's law, $\mbox{Abs} = \varepsilon \cdot c \cdot d$ -- the molecular absorption coefficient $\varepsilon$ is smaller.  While this may appear on first sight as a drawback (at same analyte concentration $c$ and  pathlength $d$, this lowers $\mbox{Abs}$ recorded), it very well may become an advantage if you want to record absorption bands about matter *in high* concentration, e.g., to check the quality of grain and crops in general  where [NIR spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-infrared_spectroscopy) is used *as such*.

IR spectroscopy has a long tradition of [chemometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemometrics), e.g. in the on-line process control of petroleum fractions where *whole spectra* are used to determine concentrations of components (e.g., keyword [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)) allowing to *map* a sample for its chemical composition as tool in histology ([a review](https://content.iospress.com/articles/biomedical-spectroscopy-and-imaging/bsi151)).  Again, tuning the senors to record NIR instead of the range of $4000\dots\pu{800 cm^{-1}}$ allows to see some things literally in a different light (e.g., [Landsat satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_program), [farming](https://crops.extension.iastate.edu/cropnews/2016/05/choosing-right-imagery-best-management-practices-color-nir-and-ndvi-imagery)).

[image]

([credit](https://www0.landgate.wa.gov.au/maps-and-imagery/imagery/aerial-photography/near-infrared-imagery))